# Nested views vs. nested states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I read the ui-router docs but I didn't understand what is the different between nested views and nested states and how its related to scope inheritance.

Thank!

Comment: I think it's just another way of describing nested states, if a parent states has a view, then the child state with another view will be nested in the view of the parent state.

Answer (score 3):

One state may have few views. Your app may be in one one state at the moment. But display many views at the moment.

So to me views is a sort of children of states if to put it into simple words.

Comment: How can a state have multiple views?